# How can I deploy a Gradle build to a maven repository (Nexus) with Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, nexus

I have a third party project that I'm having Jenkins watch. It is on Github, and Jenkins polls every hour to see if there are any changes in it, then Jenkins builds it using Gradle.

I want Jenkins to then deploy the artifacts that come from the Gradle build to Maven. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

[P.S. My apologies if this is the wrong website.]

(As a note: Since I do not own this project, it is a third-party, I can't add a deployment section to the gradle build file so that is out of the question. This is the reason why I am posting here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always inject configuration into the build using an [init script](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html). Since you have your own CI build just use the Gradle CLI `--init-script` option to point to a script which adds the Maven publishing configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would insert an init script in with Jenkins, or even what exactly to put into it but thank you. This seems to be the most correct answer.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Jenkins particulars but I'm sure you can configure the actual build command. For example `./gradlew --init-script /path/to/script.gradle build`.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you! I'm guessing in there just include deployment information and then have jenkins run it (or something?) I've never really used Gradle, so I will just have to look it up :) Thanks again @Mark.